# For loop and blocking the event loop

Tags: node.js

I am runing a web application on node and I was using this function to create async for loops, as to not block node

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
    await callback(array[i], i, array)
  }
}

// Then calling it like this 

await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => {
  // Do some validation with file if error send this
  res.status(500).send('error')
})
```

The problem I am havin is that I cannot break the loop, I am trying to run `res.status(500).send('error')` inside the loop but because it is async I end up sending `res.status(500).send('error')` multiple times if both iteration send 500 error, the idea is if any iteration sends 500 the loop should stop.

Comment: Thanks, where would you put the block at?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldnt write the code this way. I would use something like a pMap (library) for a task like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `callback` return a boolean to indicate whether to stop the loop or not:

```js
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
        const result = await callback(array[i], i, array);
        if (result) return;
    }
}

await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => {
    // Do some validation with file if error send this
    if (someCondition) {
        res.status(500).send('error');
        return true; // tell asyncForEach to stop
    }
    // If we return nothing (or something falsy like undefined/false)
    // then asyncForEach will just continue (until there are no array items left)
});
```

Alternatively, if you're using Express, you can check [response.headersSent](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.headersSent) to check whether a response has already been sent. You can make use of this in a custom `asyncForEach` or in your (wrapped) `callback` to stop executing the callbacks at that point:

```js
await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => {
    if (res.headersSent) return; // already sent a response
    if (someCondition) {
        res.status(500).send('error');
        return;
    }
});
```

Last but not least, you could technically throw a custom error and catch it:

```js
class BreakLoopError extends Error {}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
        try { await callback(array[i], i, array); } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof BreakLoopError) return; // stop executing
            // Got an unexpected error, just throw it up
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

await asyncForEach(files, async (file) => {
    if (someCondition) {
        res.status(500).send('error');
        throw new BreakLoopError();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, given the code above where would you send the boolean? ,I tried something that but the for loop did not capture the boolena change

Comment: Your loop would basically look like `if (await callback(array[i], i, array)) return;` meaning that if your callback is just `(v, i) => i == 2`, it would stop the loop every 3rd element (indexes start at 0, remember).

Comment: I really dont understand this `(v, i) => i == 2` my example has nothing like that. I am actually returning this `return res.status(500).send({ err, fileName, item })`

Comment: I meant e.g. `asyncForEach(someArray, (v, i) => i == 2)` or `asyncForEach(someArray, async (v, i) => i == 2)`. The arrow function would be called with the 0th element and 0, 1st element and 1, 2nd element and 2, etc. But during the 2nd element, `i == 2` would be `true`, therefore the `if (...) return` inside the loop would stop `asyncForEach` from continuing. I'll add an example to my answer.